# Retrieve SUM of hits from another table

Tags: php, mysql

My query is:

> SELECT * FROM sites WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY id DESC

From here, inside my while loop I have the all the urls that are active. I want to check these urls in another table `'hits`', and get the SUM of the 'stats' for each site that is active.

How can this be accomplished? Is this done with a JOIN statement?

table structures

**sites**

```
id  int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
url varchar(100)    NO  UNI     
status  int(11) YES     1   
added   timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**hits**

```
id  int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
domain  varchar(30) NO          
stats   int(11) YES     NULL    
added   timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure for both tables?

Comment: edited my question, with the table structure

Comment: How do those tables relate?  I hope you're not trying to parse `sites.url` to match `hits.domain`.

Comment: I need to get hits.stats where domain= sites.url (for each). Does that make sense?

Comment: A relation by ID would be preferable, but if the contents of those fields match exactly (despite what the different names suggest) then it's serviceable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A.id,COUNT(1) site_hits
FROM
    (SELECT id FROM sites WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id DESC) A
    INNER JOIN
    hits B ON A.id = B.site_id
GROUP BY
    A.id
;
```

CAVEAT #1 for this query : You will need a good index for this one. I recommend the following:

```
ALTER TABLE sites ADD INDEX status_id_ndx (status,id);
```

CAVEAT #2 for this query : You could make the index more efficient.

With status being int(11), you could accommodate 2147483647 possible status values. I don't think you have that many. If the highest value for status < 256, you could change it as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE sites MODIFY COLUMN status int unsigned not null;
```

Result? Smaller table, small index, and faster access.

You need something like this. I do not see any correlation between sites and hits in your question. You need the id of the site to be stored in hits table. If you are trying to join by domain against url, you will need to express the join that way. That part would seem messy. It would resemble something like this:

```
SELECT
    A.id,COUNT(1) site_hits
FROM
    sites A,hits B
WHERE
    LOCATE(B.domain,A.url)
GROUP BY
    A.id
;
```

Comment: So instead of storing the domain in hits, you're saying store the id of the domain (aka url) from the sites table?

Comment: As long as the id from sites matches the domain going into hits, then Yes. Then the first query would work for you,

Comment: Thank you for your response Rolando, very helpful! I believe I understand it now

Comment: In response to your edit, I never really knew the value for int was relevant. Does having it at a more suitable value increase performance? I usually just random pick the value for varchar & int. Do you have anything I can read up on to determine what I should set the value to? Thanks

Comment: Any SELECT query you have, just append `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()`. It will display the recommended column definitions for the current contents of a populated table. Example: `SELECT * FROM sites PROCEDURE ANALYSE();`. You can look up http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2643/877 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3216/877

Answer (score 0):

Rolando's on the right track, but to sum the stats you'll want something more like this:

```
select sites.id, sites.url, sum(hits.stats)
from sites
join hits on sites.url = hits.domain
where sites.status = 1
group by sites.id, sites.url
```

If you want sites that are active but have no hits, make the `join` a `left join`.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't notice the sum was missing from his response. So this is matching the url & domain fields exactly instead of doing it the ID way. Thank you Simon!